# I'm having an issue linking the standard crt when using clang in linux with c++

Tags: c++11, linker, clang, llvm, crt

I'm working on porting a windows project to linux so I am trying to learn/setup my build pipeline on linux(ubuntu). I use clang on windows and would like to use clang/llvm to compile my code on ubuntu but I am having an issue linking the c runtime library to my code. Here's an example of what I am trying to run just so I can set up the build scripts,

```
// -- system includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// -- my includes
#include "crt.h"

int main() {
char title[] = "Text";
int title_length = strlen(title);

// -- sending string and length to platform dependent code
CreateBox(title, title_length);

return(0); }
```

After installing clang 3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I run the above code as well as platform dependent code from the terminal,

```
clang++ -c main.cpp box_linux.cpp
```

The file compiles without error. Let's say I had  I use the following command when trying to link,

```
ld main.o box.o
```

I get back the following error every single time,

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
In function 'main':
(.text+0x30): undefined reference to 'strlen'
```

I try linking libc++, libstdc++ but nothing seems to work. I am admittedly very, *very* new to linux and clang on linux so I apologize in advance. I have checked different questions here on stackoveflow as well as ubuntu's forums and LLVM's forums/docs to no avail. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `clang` (or `gcc`) on linux you don't have to do the linking on your own. You can let `clang` do the linking for you and it will select the necessary libraries for your system just remove the `-c` flag form command line or use `clang main.o`. Clang understands that a `.o` file is already an object file and passes it on to the linker.

If you realy want to invoke `ld` on your own then start with `clang++ -v main.cpp`. The `-v` switch let clang print the invocation command for `ld` which e.g., looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/data/home/user/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/test-574b88.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! And I should have included an additional file or at least a mention to it. That was my mistake. Because I am trying to make my code platform independent I have my entry point calling a common file that handles all of the platform independent functions(i/o, grraphics, etc). As far as I know, clang and gcc will link automatically for single files but you have to do it for multiple files. I tried using the -v option but it still errored out saying 'cannot find /tmp/string-48040e.o: No such file or directory'.

Comment: @EditedContent please edit your question to reflect what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just use something like "clang -o prog main.o file1.o file2.o ...".